# Problems using longtable with a table from tablesgenerator.com

Tags: page-breaking, longtable

I've tried my best to find a solution to this problem by reading different questions/forums, but I simply cannot figure it out: I have a table (made from tablesgenerator.com) that is too long for one page, and I have tried to implement the longtable package, but it is not working.. Any help is much appreciated!

(This it the original code directly from the generator).

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{llllll}
Index                                                  &                       &   & Statistic & \textit{df} & Sig.           \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Perimeter}                             & \multirow{2}{*}{Pre}  & C & 0,966     & 8           & 0,862          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,935     & 8           & 0,560          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                       & \multirow{2}{*}{Post} & C & 0,931     & 8           & 0,524          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,995     & 8           & 1,000          \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Area}                                  & \multirow{2}{*}{Pre}  & C & 0,898     & 8           & 0,279          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,951     & 8           & 0,718          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                       & \multirow{2}{*}{Post} & C & 0,951     & 8           & 0,717          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,963     & 8           & 0,834          \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Form Factor}                           & \multirow{2}{*}{Pre}  & C & 0,975     & 8           & 0,934          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,940     & 8           & 0,613          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                       & \multirow{2}{*}{Post} & C & 0,939     & 8           & 0,606          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,699     & 8           & \textbf{0,002} \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Perimeter - Area Ratio of Convex Hull} & \multirow{2}{*}{Pre}  & C & 0,887     & 8           & 0,222          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,852     & 8           & 0,100          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                       & \multirow{2}{*}{Post} & C & 0,983     & 8           & 0,978          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,962     & 8           & 0,833          \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Area - Maximum Area Ratio}             & \multirow{2}{*}{Pre}  & C & 0,977     & 8           & 0,948          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,965     & 8           & 0,853          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                       & \multirow{2}{*}{Post} & C & 0,966     & 8           & 0,865          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,931     & 8           & 0,522          \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Ratio of Radii}                        & \multirow{2}{*}{Pre}  & C & 0,970     & 8           & 0,897          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,967     & 8           & 0,877          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                       & \multirow{2}{*}{Post} & C & 0,958     & 8           & 0,793          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,924     & 8           & 0,465          \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Global Convex Deficiency}              & \multirow{2}{*}{Pre}  & C & 0,972     & 8           & 0,915          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,917     & 8           & 0,404          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                       & \multirow{2}{*}{Post} & C & 0,949     & 8           & 0,704          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,821     & 8           & \textbf{0,048} \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Rugosity}                              & \multirow{2}{*}{Pre}  & C & 0,790     & 9           & \textbf{0,023} \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,888     & 8           & 0,223          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                       & \multirow{2}{*}{Post} & C & 0,837     & 8           & 0,070          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,682     & 8           & \textbf{0,001} \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Horizontal Vertices Symmetry}          & \multirow{2}{*}{Pre}  & C & 0,980     & 8           & 0,965          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,936     & 8           & 0,572          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                       & \multirow{2}{*}{Post} & C & 0,931     & 8           & 0,528          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,937     & 8           & 0,586          \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Vertical Vertices Symmetry}            & \multirow{2}{*}{Pre}  & C & 0,941     & 8           & 0,620          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,848     & 8           & 0,092          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                       & \multirow{2}{*}{Post} & C & 0,928     & 8           & 0,499          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,946     & 8           & 0,675          \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Left Right Area Symmetry}              & \multirow{2}{*}{Pre}  & C & 0,924     & 8           & 0,466          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,844     & 8           & 0,083          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                       & \multirow{2}{*}{Post} & C & 0,922     & 8           & 0,448          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,925     & 8           & 0,469          \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Top Bottom Area Symmetry}              & \multirow{2}{*}{Pre}  & C & 0,847     & 8           & 0,090          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,834     & 8           & 0,066          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                       & \multirow{2}{*}{Post} & C & 0,786     & 8           & \textbf{0,020} \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,911     & 8           & 0,363          \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Horizontal Symmetry of Convex Hull}    & \multirow{2}{*}{Pre}  & C & 0,841     & 8           & 0,077          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,964     & 8           & 0,847          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                       & \multirow{2}{*}{Post} & C & 0,904     & 8           & 0,315          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,925     & 8           & 0,473          \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Vertical Symmetry of Convex Hull}      & \multirow{2}{*}{Pre}  & C & 0,767     & 8           & \textbf{0,012} \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,950     & 8           & 0,713          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                       & \multirow{2}{*}{Post} & C & 0,752     & 8           & \textbf{0,009} \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,856     & 8           & 0,109          \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Elongation}                            & \multirow{2}{*}{Pre}  & C & 0,908     & 8           & 0,337          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,880     & 8           & 0,187          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                       & \multirow{2}{*}{Post} & C & 0,927     & 8           & 0,489          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,843     & 8           & 0,081          \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Regularity}                            & \multirow{2}{*}{Pre}  & C & 0,760     & 8           & \textbf{0,010} \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,940     & 8           & 0,607          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                       & \multirow{2}{*}{Post} & C & 0,948     & 8           & 0,691          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,960     & 8           & 0,808          \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: @koleygr thank you for the edit, I tried doing the MWE format thing, but it obviously didn't work (as you can probably tell I am brand new to Latex).

Comment: OffQustionTopic-OnCommentTopic: You have to paste the code (as you did) and after that, select all of it and press the button `{}`. Welcome!

Comment: Hi, welcome. This looks to be quite similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/424435/help-with-long-table-from-stargazer/424438#424438, does that description help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{llllll}
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}\\
Index&&& Statistic & \textit{df} & Sig.\\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Perimeter}                             & \multirow{2}{*}{Pre}  & C & 0,966     & 8           & 0,862          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,935     & 8           & 0,560          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                       & \multirow{2}{*}{Post} & C & 0,931     & 8           & 0,524          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,995     & 8           & 1,000          \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Area}                                  & \multirow{2}{*}{Pre}  & C & 0,898     & 8           & 0,279          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,951     & 8           & 0,718          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                       & \multirow{2}{*}{Post} & C & 0,951     & 8           & 0,717          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,963     & 8           & 0,834          \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Form Factor}                           & \multirow{2}{*}{Pre}  & C & 0,975     & 8           & 0,934          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,940     & 8           & 0,613          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                       & \multirow{2}{*}{Post} & C & 0,939     & 8           & 0,606          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,699     & 8           & \textbf{0,002} \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Perimeter - Area Ratio of Convex Hull} & \multirow{2}{*}{Pre}  & C & 0,887     & 8           & 0,222          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,852     & 8           & 0,100          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                       & \multirow{2}{*}{Post} & C & 0,983     & 8           & 0,978          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,962     & 8           & 0,833          \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Area - Maximum Area Ratio}             & \multirow{2}{*}{Pre}  & C & 0,977     & 8           & 0,948          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,965     & 8           & 0,853          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                       & \multirow{2}{*}{Post} & C & 0,966     & 8           & 0,865          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,931     & 8           & 0,522          \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Ratio of Radii}                        & \multirow{2}{*}{Pre}  & C & 0,970     & 8           & 0,897          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,967     & 8           & 0,877          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                       & \multirow{2}{*}{Post} & C & 0,958     & 8           & 0,793          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,924     & 8           & 0,465          \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Global Convex Deficiency}              & \multirow{2}{*}{Pre}  & C & 0,972     & 8           & 0,915          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,917     & 8           & 0,404          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                       & \multirow{2}{*}{Post} & C & 0,949     & 8           & 0,704          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,821     & 8           & \textbf{0,048} \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Rugosity}                              & \multirow{2}{*}{Pre}  & C & 0,790     & 9           & \textbf{0,023} \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,888     & 8           & 0,223          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                       & \multirow{2}{*}{Post} & C & 0,837     & 8           & 0,070          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,682     & 8           & \textbf{0,001} \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Horizontal Vertices Symmetry}          & \multirow{2}{*}{Pre}  & C & 0,980     & 8           & 0,965          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,936     & 8           & 0,572          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                       & \multirow{2}{*}{Post} & C & 0,931     & 8           & 0,528          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,937     & 8           & 0,586          \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Vertical Vertices Symmetry}            & \multirow{2}{*}{Pre}  & C & 0,941     & 8           & 0,620          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,848     & 8           & 0,092          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                       & \multirow{2}{*}{Post} & C & 0,928     & 8           & 0,499          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,946     & 8           & 0,675          \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Left Right Area Symmetry}              & \multirow{2}{*}{Pre}  & C & 0,924     & 8           & 0,466          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,844     & 8           & 0,083          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                       & \multirow{2}{*}{Post} & C & 0,922     & 8           & 0,448          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,925     & 8           & 0,469          \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Top Bottom Area Symmetry}              & \multirow{2}{*}{Pre}  & C & 0,847     & 8           & 0,090          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,834     & 8           & 0,066          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                       & \multirow{2}{*}{Post} & C & 0,786     & 8           & \textbf{0,020} \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,911     & 8           & 0,363          \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Horizontal Symmetry of Convex Hull}    & \multirow{2}{*}{Pre}  & C & 0,841     & 8           & 0,077          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,964     & 8           & 0,847          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                       & \multirow{2}{*}{Post} & C & 0,904     & 8           & 0,315          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,925     & 8           & 0,473          \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Vertical Symmetry of Convex Hull}      & \multirow{2}{*}{Pre}  & C & 0,767     & 8           & \textbf{0,012} \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,950     & 8           & 0,713          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                       & \multirow{2}{*}{Post} & C & 0,752     & 8           & \textbf{0,009} \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,856     & 8           & 0,109          \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Elongation}                            & \multirow{2}{*}{Pre}  & C & 0,908     & 8           & 0,337          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,880     & 8           & 0,187          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                       & \multirow{2}{*}{Post} & C & 0,927     & 8           & 0,489          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,843     & 8           & 0,081          \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Regularity}                            & \multirow{2}{*}{Pre}  & C & 0,760     & 8           & \textbf{0,010} \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,940     & 8           & 0,607          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                       & \multirow{2}{*}{Post} & C & 0,948     & 8           & 0,691          \\
                                                       &                       & T & 0,960     & 8           & 0,808          \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Just did the below:

1) changed your table environment to longtable

2) removed tabular environment and placed its first argument `{llllll}` naex to long table

3) finished a line  (added a `\\`) after `\caption` and \label commands.

PS: Also added the `longtable` and `multirow` packages an a simple "article template"

Comment: Thank you so much, it works for me as well!
I had apparently misunderstood where to place the \\. Thank you for saving my bachelors report!

Comment: Welcome... You may accept the answer but sometimes followup answers are coming after some time. They may show you how to create better looking tables etc. (If you don't want something like this, because of automating things via programming or whatever, please make it clear for the next possible "answerers" to not try). Also, please try next time to provide a real MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)... In your case it was just two three more commands... But is good anyway...